# in Flutter how to Prevent items in ListView.builder to be rebuilt when scroll back?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview

I know if I am not mistaken that ListView builds the widget that are currently visible, and you can use cacheExtent to build items before viewing it, however it works in one direction as it caches the element below the current item, so when I scroll down some items are already built which is fine, however when I scroll back up, the previously built items are being rebuilt which is a behaviour I don't want for a number of items above the visible part, so I want to use cacheExtent in both directions above the visible item and below it.. is this possible?